# How label tag works in HTML

Tags: html

```
<form action="https://google.com" method="get">
  <label for="id">Enter:</label>
  <input id= "id1" type="text" name="" placeholder="Notlabebeld">
  <input id= "id" type="text" name="" value="Labeled">
</form>
```

how this label tag works, i want to label 2nd input tag, but that's not what i get after this.
I know by writing label after first input tag, that will give desired result. Just want to know how it works :#
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a label to the input field has no effect on its positioning., it is mostly programmatic association. For text fields, it means that clicking on the label will focus the text field, for check-boxes, it will toggle the checkbox etc. Also, it is used by screen readers. You can place the input field at the bottom of the page and its label to the top of the page and still connect them using `id` and `for`.
There is great a documentation with examples on Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label